# Software for computing Möbius function of a poset

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, math-software, mobius-function

Is there any software available (possibly free) for computing the Möbius function of a finite partially ordered set (poset) and related things?

For a definition of Möbius function of a poset see this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra

Thank you.